# Ubuntu desktop machine on cloud

Tags: desktop-environments, cloud

I'm trying to find a supplier for a single machine running Ubuntu for private use. From what I can see, most classical vendors, such as Google, Amazon and Microsoft, target professional customers with lots of machines at a high cost.

Does anyone know of a supplier providing what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: I think the OP needs to stress that a ***desktop*** VPS solution is sought.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because VPS recommendations are shopping questions and offtopic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://contabo.com/?show=ssdvps&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=vps&gclid=Cj0KCQjw3qzzBRDnARIsAECmryoF6c3iL3HZr6g1mIGMwu5QZMTG_GIljglgckcJHGro8QoSnMGys1saAi2rEALw_wcB) a powerful VPS configuration, but I didn't try it. [GUI installation](https://contabo.com/?show=tutorials&tutorial=installation-of-a-graphical-user-interface-for-linux) is not hard for it:

> Ubuntu 18.10 and later versions
>
> Please connect to your server as root via SSH. Create a new user for
>   your GUI login and set a password:
>
> ```
> useradd -m NewUserName && passwd NewUserName
> ```
>
> You can choose from a variety of GUIs, which will automatically be
>   installed with the `tasksel` tool:
>
> ```
> apt update && apt upgrade -y && tasksel
> ```
>
> Some GUIs might require the `lightdm` display manager, instead of the
>   `gdm3` manager that comes preinstalled with Ubuntu. If your desktop
>   does not load properly, please install `lightdm`:
>
> ```
> apt install lightdm
> ```
>
> Choose a desktop of your liking and confirm, please do not install
>   multiple desktop environments at the same time. Reboot your server to
>   make your GUI accessible via your VPS VNC access or KVM in case of a
>   dedicated server.

Here is also a [tutorial](https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-vps/) on [hostwinds](https://www.hostwinds.com/vps/linux) for how to install Ubuntu desktop on VPS. But theirs prices and VPS configurations are not attractive.

OVH also provides [desktop option](https://www.ovh.com/world/dedicated-servers/distributions/ubuntu_desktop.xml), but only for Xubuntu 16.04 as it could be seen in [the list](https://www.ovh.com/world/dedicated-servers/distributions/) which seems to me outdated. You could contact them and ask if they provide ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an Ubuntu ***Desktop*** VPS solution. Although you can install additional packages to convert an Ubuntu Server to a Desktop, it may be more appropriate to point to a Cloud Provider which has already optimized Ubuntu Desktop VPSs accessible remotely with RDP, VNC, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I won't use it as a server, but rather as a desktop to run applications such as Anaconda. This looks promising, but I was hoping to find an offering all set up with Ubuntu and Unity.

Answer (score 0):

On MS Azure, I run lots of VM with Ubuntu 18.04 . Install x2go to get remote gui interaction. This is better than plain X11 for me. I find xfce4 desktop works well. If you have seen VNC desktop or MS remote desktop, this will be familiar to you.

Cost is about $40 per month per core, RAM size affects cost. Seems expensive, but you are using somebody else's computer.

If you need more power, you are smarter to buy hardware.